# Rails error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My rails app is getting this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
```

The line in my model that it is complaining about is this:

```
validates :body, presence: true, 
          length: {minimum: 2, maximum: 1000}, 
          :chat_room_id, :user_id
```

Seems to be the comma between `:chat_room_id` and `:user_id`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot write validation condition and after that, what to validate:

If presume you want something like this:

```
validates :body, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2, maximum: 1000}
validates :chat_room_id, :user_id, presence: true
```

Or another option:

```
validates :body, :chat_room_id, :user_id, presence: true
validates :body, length: {minimum: 2, maximum: 1000}
```

Answer (score 0):

My parameter list:
{:utf8, :authenticity_token, :worklog => {:typee, :do, :todo, :feel, :plan_done, :plan, :week_feel, :score, :good, :nogood}, :commit}

after add thoes parameter get empty value in database